# Connection to Microstoft SSM Studio 18 with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ssms

I'm trying to connect my table `Cities_names` in NetBeans.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr9Na.png

I don't really know why i'm having the error: `Connection failed: The connection to the host sqlsrv, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: sqlsrv". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host. (jdbc:sqlserver://sqlsrv\sqlexpress;databaseName=Cities_names using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)`

What should I write instead?

Comment: SSMS is an IDE; you don't connect to it at all.

Comment: Ok, so how can I connect :(?

Comment: You connect to SQL Server, *not* SSMS. As for why it's failing, it appears that your connection details are wrong. Is the host that SQL Server is running on really called `sqlsrv`?

Comment: Nope. I saw that's not :) ` SELECT @@SERVERNAME` and found it. Thank you :)